# postfix/smtp dns lookup A record fails

Tags: dns, smtp, postfix-mta

I configured another postfix relay server today. For now I closed all incoming ports, so when I send E-Mails through a transport relay I talk to the local unix smtp client.
When I call this through `postqueue -f` it says

`[root@dev-core-mailhub1 postfix]# Apr  5 15:10:49 dev-core-mailhub1 postfix/smtp[5499]: 37812C81B03: to=<XXXXXXX>, relay=none, delay=4923, delays=4923/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=XXXXXX type=A: Host not found, try again)`

But when I lookup the host on the system I get the address!

So I digged a bit deeper and did an `strace -p 5499` before I forced the queue again.

`connect(16, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0`

So the tool tries to resolve against localhost! But `/etc/resolv.conf` sais something completely different!

Why is that so?

How can I configure postfix/smtp to either obey `/etc/resolv.conf` or use another configurered resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys you are not fast enough: I found that postfix/smtp is run in chrooted environment, so all I need is to copy /etc/resolv.conf to /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf. Then everything is inplace.